# Xamarin forms ToolbarItems WPF secondary

Tags: wpf, xamarin, xamarin.forms, toolbaritems

I have this code to set up toolbar items in XAML.

```
  <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Name="Menu1" Activated="OnClick"  Order="Primary" Priority="{StaticResource Priority1}" />
        <ToolbarItem Name="Menu2" Activated="OnClick"  Order="Secondary" Priority="{StaticResource Priority2}" />
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

The rendering is fine in Android , but in WPF I see an ugly square icon (is a placeholder for a missing icon?)

Any ideas?

[WPF render example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sahUw.jpg)

[Android render example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDgxS.jpg)

Comment: You can use ContentPage Custom Renderer to be same effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an icon for the [`Toolbaritem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/Xamarin.Forms.ToolbarItem?view=xamarin-forms) in the Assets folder.

Also, try updating the Xamarin.Forms version - with version 3.3.0.967583 I can not observe placeholder icons.

Please note that the `Name` and `Activated` properties are obsolete - use `Text` and `Clicked`, respectively:

```
<ToolbarItem Text="Menu1" 
             Icon="{OnPlatform WPF=Assets/menu1.png}"
             Order="Primary"
             Clicked="OnToolbarItemClicked" />
<ToolbarItem Text="Menu2" 
             Icon="{OnPlatform WPF=Assets/menu2.png}"
             Order="Secondary"
             Clicked="OnToolbarItemClicked" />
```

Comment: i'm using XF 3.4.0.1008975